# Error on CiviCRM Installer Page

Tags: wordpress, installation, mysql

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/install/index.php on line 769

I'm also receiving the following under PHP Configuration:
MySQL support not included in PHP.

I'm using Wordpress Version 4.6.1, CiviCRM Version 4.7.12, and PHP Version 5.5

I'm not sure if they're related issues or not.

Any advice?

Thank you

Comment: Could you please update your question to include your WordPress version, the version of CiviCRM you're trying to install, and your PHP version?  Thanks!

Comment: @evan Are you able to connect to your MySQL database normally outwith CiviCRM?

Comment: @JonG The post is updated

Comment: @termdark yes, my Wordpress installation is currently connected to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you might be getting affected by this switch to require the mysqli extension: https://civicrm.org/blog/totten/psa-please-verify-php-extension-mysqli